# Java Robot : how to click on first text highlighted (using the search function) in a browser?

Tags: java, bots

I am building a java robot that after a search of a keyword in a browser the mouse will move directly to this instance of this keyword (which is highlighted).

My problem is a I do not know the position (x,y) in advance I cannot use mouseMove(x,y).

[image: Please see the file attached.]

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have made the update.

Comment: Since your browser probably does not expose and API for Java (does it?), you won't be able to give your robot the coordinates from your browser. The only option I can think of is using image analysis packages to detect the highlighted searched word and then give its position to the robot. Maybe also have a look at Selenium.

Comment: Personally I will prefer the use of an image analysis packages. Thanks.

Comment: Why Java for this? Well maybe you should check out the OpenCV java stuffs for the OCR

Comment: Does this question have any relevance for hawtio, since you tagged the question with hawtio? If not can you remove the tag please.

Comment: Apparently it was added b mistake.Just removed it also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this, assuming you don't want to rewrite a browser from scratch in Java, is to use Robot.createScreenCapture() to create a BufferedImage, then iterate over the pixels of the image to find the highlight color.

The problem is that other things in the browser window might be that color, in which case you'll have to be more clever to go to the correct place.

Shameless self-promotion: A while ago I created a program that did exactly that, in order to automatically click the "I'm Still Listening" button on Pandora. Pandora has since changed the look of their button so it doesn't work anymore, but the code is still available if you want to check it out: http://staticvoidgames.com/games/StillListening

Edit: This also assumes that the highlight color is always the same. You might want to check that assumption before diving in.